# Show a new View from Button press Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I would like to be able to show a new view when a button is pressed on one of my views.

From the tutorials I have looked at and other answered questions here it seems like everyone is using navigation button within a navigation view, unless im mistaken navigation view is the one that gives me a menu bar right arrows the top of my app so I don't want that. when I put the navigation button in my view that wasn't a child of NavigationView it was just disabled on the UI and I couldn't click it, so I guess I cant use that.

The other examples I have seen seem to use presentation links / buttons which seem to show a sort of pop over view.

Im just looking for how to click a regular button and show another a view full screen just like performing a segue used to in the old way of doing things.

Comment: #1. In `UIKit` there are two ways to perform a 'segue". The first uses a `Storyboard`, which (explicitly) doesn't exist in `SwiftUI`. The second? `UINavigationController`. When you push/pop it's "stack" you get the animations for free. Yes, you *can* set it's title, and left/right buttons to "appear" as nothing, but you *still* have the bar. About the only thing you can do in UIKit besides this (and of course, presenting a new view modally) is to create a container view with the subviews you want and also create the animations to "look" like a segue.

Comment: #2. Without writing all this in `UIKit` and then creating a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, you probably are left with using a `NavigationView` and "hiding" the things you don't like via a `ZStack`, placing views that will obscure those views.

Comment: guess its going to have to be a navigation view then, seems pretty crap that you cant just present a new view without a navigation bar though and then hiding a load of stuff you don't want to see

Comment: If you understand my first comment, you really cannot do that in `UIKit` either. It's really not about "navigation" or "segue", it's about the stack. The kind of container view I described you can code in `UIKit`, along with the animations almost entirely in a `UIView` (and entirely without a stack), but you'd still need a view controller to actually connect it to a `UIButton`. (I've actually done this and ended up embedding a `UINavigationController` as a child VC.) Maybe Apple will expand on this in a future version of SwiftUI, but Im personally hoping the do a "Share" view first.

Comment: You can hide the navigation bar by doing `.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)`. And if you want it clickable I guess you can just make a `MainView` with the `NavigationView` only and all the other views in separate files. I'm sure they'll fix the latter one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple example you can use something like below

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleFlag : View {
    @State var flag = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if flag {
                ExampleView().tapAction {
                    self.flag.toggle()
                }
            } else {
                OtherExampleView().tapAction {
                    self.flag.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ExampleView: View {
     var body: some View {
        Text("some text")
    }
}
struct OtherExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("other text")
    }
}
```

but if you want to present more view this way looks nasty

You can use stack to control view state without NavigationView

For Example:

```
    class NavigationStack: BindableObject {
        let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

        var list: [AuthState] = []

        public func push(state: AuthState) {
            list.append(state)
            didChange.send()
        }
        public func pop() {
            list.removeLast()
            didChange.send()
        }
    }

    enum AuthState {
        case mainScreenState
        case userNameScreen
        case logginScreen
        case emailScreen
        case passwordScreen
    }
    struct NavigationRoot : View {
        @EnvironmentObject var state: NavigationStack
        @State private var aligment = Alignment.leading

        fileprivate func CurrentView() -> some View {
            switch state.list.last {
            case .mainScreenState:
                return AnyView(GalleryState())
            case .none:
                return AnyView(LoginScreen().environmentObject(state))
            default:
                return AnyView(AuthenticationView().environmentObject(state))
            }
        }
        var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.CurrentView()
                .background(Image("background")
                    .animation(.fluidSpring())
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height,
                           alignment: self.aligment))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation() {
                            switch self.state.list.last {
                            case .none:
                                    self.aligment = Alignment.leading
                            case .passwordScreen:
                                    self.aligment = Alignment.trailing
                            default:
                                    self.aligment = Alignment.center
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            .background(Color.black)
        }

}

struct ExampleOfAddingNewView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: NavigationStack
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(action:{ self.state.push(state: .emailScreen) }){
                Text("Tap me")
            }

        }
    }
}


    struct ExampleOfRemovingView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var state: NavigationStack
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(action:{ self.state.pop() }){
                    Text("Tap me")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my opinion this bad way, but navigation in SwiftUI much worse

Comment: In what way does that first example navigate to a new view?

Comment: I edit first example, that's not about 'navigation', it's just switch one view to another without any stack.

Comment: `BindableObject` was replaced by `ObservableObject` ...

Answer (score 22):

Possible solutions

1.if you want to present on top of current view(ex: presentation style in UIKit)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingDetail = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingDetail.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Detail")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}
```

2.if you want to reset current window scene stack(ex:after login show home screen)

```
Button(action: goHome) {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Spacer()
        Text("Login").foregroundColor(Color.white).bold()
        Spacer()
    }
}

func goHome() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: HomeScreen())
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

3.push new view (ex: list->detail, navigation controller of UIKit)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4.update the current view based on @state property, (ex:show error message on login failure)

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State var error = true
        var body: some View {
            ...
            ... //login email
            .. //login password
            if error {
                Text("Failed to login")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your second solution saved my life after some days searching for it, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The second option didnt include 'Button', and if you did put in a Button, there is still an issue, you can navigate to that view without actually clicking the button, but the surroundings, which maybe an Apple flaw (there are many). Try if yourself, wrap a button with a NavigationLink and click at one of the corners of the button (just outside or at the boarder of the button) and it navigates to the destination.

Comment: #1 was exactly what I needed after days of searching lol. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Update : UIApplication.shared.windows was deprecated in iOS 15.0

New way of doing the same :

```
 let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    if let window = windowScene?.windows.first {
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: YourNewView())
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```