# SwiftUI open another view on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Am trying to navigate to another view page. I tried many methods but none worked. If there is a way to navigate to another page without navigationtool... then it will be much help full

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var fname: String = ""
    @State var lname: String = ""
    @State var num: String = ""
    @State var pass: String = ""
    @State private var registerionAlert = false
    @State private var registerionAlertActive: ActiveAlert = .success
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Form {
                Text("Registeration Form")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 25.0)
                TextField("Enter your first name...", text: $fname)
                    .padding()
                    .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                TextField("Enter your last name...", text: $lname)
                    .padding()
                    .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                TextField("Enter your phone number...", text: $num)
                    .padding()
                    .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                TextField("Enter a password...", text: $pass)
                    .padding()
                    .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Button(action: {
                    self.registerTapped()
                }) {
                    Text("Register")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                .padding(0.0)
                .frame(width: 150.0, height: 30.0)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.green/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .accentColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.white/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .cornerRadius(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/5.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .offset(x: 95.0, y: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .alert(isPresented: $registerionAlert){
                    switch registerionAlertActive {
                    case .success:
                        return Alert(
                            title: Text("Register"),
                            message: Text("Registered Successfully"),
                            dismissButton: .default(
                                Text("Got it!"),
                                action: {
                                    loginView()
                                    print("success")
                                }
                            )
                        )
                    case .failed:
                        return Alert(
                            title: Text("Register"),
                            message: Text("Registered Unsuccessful, Try again later."),
                            dismissButton: .default(
                                Text("Got it!"))
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
            .padding(10.0)
            .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.orange/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
    
    func registerTapped() {
        
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "first_name": "\(fname)",
            "last_name": "\(lname)",
            "phone": "\(num)",
            "password": "\(pass)"
        ]
        
        AF.request(
            "http://192.168.0.9/mobile-api/public/register",
            method: .post,
            parameters: params,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default
        ).validate().responseString() {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                self.registerionAlertActive = .success
                break
            case .failure(_):
                self.registerionAlertActive = .failed
                break
            }
            self.registerionAlert = true
        }
    }
        
}
```

my another page is given below in which i haven't add much of things is only sample views

```
import SwiftUI

struct loginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct loginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        loginView()
    }
}
```

please help me navigate to another page

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104813/change-the-root-view-of-uihostingcontroller-in-swiftui/58105259#58105259

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a new View from Button press Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966739/show-a-new-view-from-button-press-swift-ui)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var isOpen: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isOpen = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Tap me")
                    .foregroundColor(obj_saved_color.set_color)
            }).sheet(isPresented: $isOpen, content: {
               SecondView()
            })
        }
    }
}}

struct SecondView: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Second View")
    }
}}
```

Comment: I have no knowledge on this ... so my question may feel like silly.. anyway... isnt there anything like we can do it in js.. like window.location.href = secondview() . something like that?

Comment: Thanks it worked. But i comes up like a popup sheet. I need it to redirect ti that view

Comment: I don't have an idea about js, check this maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958858/present-a-new-view-in-swiftui @RantoBerk