# Change the view when a button is pressed in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to change the view when I press the button in SwiftUI.

```
ZStack {
    Button(action: {
        Settings(logOutAfter24H: true, emailAddress: "example@example.com")
        print("Button pressed")
    }) {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .frame(width: 125, height: 150).foregroundColor(Color.CGreen)
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                Text("Settings").foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to switch to the `Settings` view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a new View from Button press Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966739/show-a-new-view-from-button-press-swift-ui)

Comment: I tired using the code that had been given there but it didn't work for me.

Comment: How do you want to present your view? Do you just want to replace your current View?

Comment: Yes, if I can make it a overlay that would be preferd but if I can replace the current view that should also be fine.

Comment: I am getting the error - "Result of 'Settings' initializer is unused"

Comment: I updated my answer to include an overlay (sheet) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your current View to be replaced with the SettingsView, you can try:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSettingsView = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showSettingsView {
                Settings(...)
            } else {
                settingsButton
            }
        }
    }
    
    var settingsButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSettingsView = true
            print("Button pressed")
        }) {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .frame(width: 125, height: 150).foregroundColor(.green)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Settings").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By setting the value of `showSettingsView` you can decide whether to show or hide SettingsView.

Alternatively you can use a `NavigationLink` to push a new View on the navigation stack or use a `sheet` to present a view modally:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSettingsView = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            settingsButton
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsView) {
            Settings(...)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a sheet for it or a navigation link. For a sheet, make an @State var called show = false. Then say self.show.toggle() in the button action, and then at the closing bracket of the parent view stack or the closing bracket for the button you can say **.sheet** and do the binding with $show and then for content, just say Settings().
If you want to make a navigation link instead, just delete the button and instead say NavigationLink(destination: Settings() { "configure button appearance here" }